# Cannot adjust font size of the uilabel to its height

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I want to make a different label on different iOS devices, but I cannot change its font size accordingly to its height. Well, I can, however only if I don't set a font first and that's a problem because I need this font. The function (I'm using SnapKit for layout):

```
fileprivate func initNameLabel() {
        let user = UserManager.shared.getCurrentUser()
        self.userNameLabel = UILabel()
        self.userNameLabel?.text = user?.fullName
        self.userNameLabel?.font = .openSans(size: Sizes.userNameLabelFont)
        self.userNameLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
        self.userNameLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        self.userNameLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.containerView?.addSubview(self.userNameLabel!)

        self.userNameLabel?.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.avatarImageView!.snp.bottom).offset(Sizes.offset)
            make.height.equalTo(Sizes.userNameLabelHeight)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.containerView!.snp.centerX)
        })
    }
```

And the font extension:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func openSans(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: size) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size)
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "only if I don't set a font first", on what case this does work for you?

Comment: this does not work with line: 
self.userNameLabel?.font = .openSans(size: Sizes.userNameLabelFont)
Otherwise it works